# Increase Bluetooth Low Energy TX/RX Power Linux

Tags: c++, bluetooth

I want to increase the TX (and preferably also RX) power to increase the bluetooth low energy range of my setup. Via command line I tried:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 inqtpl <POWER>
```

This is supposed to set the transmit power but it doesn't. First of all I cannot enter negative values, why? The power remains 4 for whatever power I enter in the command. To get the current power I used:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 inqtpl
```

I tried doing the same in a C++ program of mine, shown below in a slimmed down format:

```
hciSocket = hci_open_dev(hciDeviceId);
hci_le_set_advertise_enable(hciSocket, 0, 1000);
hci_le_set_advertise_enable(hciSocket, 1, 1000);
if(hci_le_set_advertise_enable(hciSocket, 0, 1000) == -1)
  cout << "Failed to disable advertising\n";
if (hci_write_inquiry_transmit_power_level(hciSocket, 10 , 1000) < 0)
  cout << "Failed to set power\n";
hci_read_inquiry_transmit_power_level(hciSocket, level , 1000); 
cout << "Device power is set to " << (int) *level << "\n";
```

This code (run with sudo privileges) gave me no errors but also wasn't able to change the power level.

How *can* I change the power level?